# Adding a column based on the values from another dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe created using the following data.

```
data = {'B1':[65, 41, 17, 7], 
        'B2':[28, 40, 47, 30],
        'B3':[16, 29, 39, 44],
        'L':[6, 6.5, 7, 7.5]
        'U':[6.5, 7, 7.5, 8]}
df=pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I have another dataframe `df1` as follows:

```
data1 = {'Value':[6, 6.5, 7, 7.5]}
df1=pd.DataFrame(data1)
```

For each row in `df1`, I want to get the row from `df`where the value is between the `'L'` and `'U'` values and get the column name of the maximum value of the other columns and add it as a column to `df1`. For example, the output can be seen in the image below:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DohAW.png)

Here is the code I used:

```
maxval=[]
for index,row in df1.iterrows():
   tmp_val=df[df.columns[0:3]][(row.Value>= df.L) &(row.Value<df.U)]
   maxval.append(tmp_val.idxmax(axis=1))
```

I then add this column to `df1`. While this works, I have a dataframe that has 300,000 rows and it is taking a long time to do this. Are there any other ways to do this quicker?

Comment: are both of your dataframe 300k rows?

Comment: Length of ```df``` is at maximum 10 rows. However, ```df1``` is 300,000 rows.

Answer (score 1):

Using [`idxmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html):

```
df1.assign(max_col=df.idxmax(1))

    Value max_col
0    6.0      B1
1    6.5      B1
2    7.0      B2
3    7.5      B3
```

---

We can speed it up a little more working with the underlying numpy arrays and using `argmax`:

```
df1.assign(max_col=df.columns[df.values.argmax(1)])
```

Comment: Sorry, I just updated the question and added the 'U' column.

Comment: Pleas share the expected output @labalala

Comment: Its in the image attached.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, your `df['U']` is `df['L']` shifted by 1. If so, you can still use `idxmax` but with a `pd.cut`:

```
row_map = pd.cut(df1['Value'], bins = [df['L'][0]] + df['U'].to_list(),
                 right=False,
                 labels=df.index)

df1['max_col'] = df.loc[row_map,df.columns[:3]].idxmax(1)
```

Output:

```
   Value max_col
0    6.0      B1
1    6.5      B1
2    7.0      B2
3    7.5      B3
```